# Bubbles as symbols for plots

Tags: plotting, charts

I have been interested in using bubbles as symbols for a `ListPlot`. I am aware of the power of Mathematica. I think that is possible. Is there anyone who has an experience with it? I mean bubbles in the below shapes (albeit in smaller size):

[image]

Comment: For similar queries, you can use: `Names["*Bubble*"]` and then explore each entry using the docs by pressing F1.

Comment: Or search the documentation with `bubble`

Comment: I had seen documents for Bubbles. But the results as the below answer is not desired. The symbols are solid sphere not bubbles I think. I wish to have bubbles.

Comment: You can use any type of [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) or even [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) for your plot markers. Please see the examples in the documentation for [`PlotMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

data = RandomReal[1, {10, 3}];
```

With [`BubbleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html) the bubbles are not spheres, although they can be given the appearance of spheres. Note that the Head is [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) (i.e., 2D) so there are no spheres (3D)

```
Head@BubbleChart[data]

(* Graphics *)
```

There are several built-in choices for [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html)

```
ChartElementData["BubbleChart"]

(* {"Bubble", "FadingBubble", "GradientBubble", "MarkerBubble", "NoiseBubble", \
"OscillatingBubble", "PolyhedronBubble", "SphereBubble", "SquareWaveBubble", \
"TriangleWaveBubble"} *)
```

Comparing,

```
BubbleChart[data,
   ChartElementFunction -> #,
   PlotLabel -> #] & /@
 ChartElementData["BubbleChart"]
```

[image]